# Conflicting types error for void function

Tags: c, function

```
void makeMoveReplace();    
void makeMoveReplace(char board[][SIZE*SIZE], char char1, char char2){
        int i=0, j=0;
        if(char1 == '\n' || char1 == ' ')
            printf("Error");
        for(i; i < SIZE*SIZE;i++){
            for(j; j < SIZE*SIZE; j++){
                if(board[i][j] == char1)
                    board[i][j] = char2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Conflicting types for 'makeMoveReplace' - The error I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the function signature, therefore change:

```
void makeMoveReplace();
```

to

```
void makeMoveReplace(char board[][SIZE*SIZE], char char1, char char2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Function declaration should match, with the function definition.

Change the funtion declaration statement:
`void makeMoveReplace();` to `void makeMoveReplace(char [][SIZE*SIZE], char, char);`